# Learning React: Trouble understanding why my component won't render/ API/KEYS

Tags: reactjs, api, render

I am fairly new to learning React and need some help.
I want to create a meal finder app using the [MealDb API](https://www.themealdb.com/api.php), my problem is it won't render.

**Here is my code, in my app component:**

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react';
 import './App.css';
 import Search from './components/Search';
 import Meals from './components/Meals';
 import axios from 'axios';

 function App() {
 const [meals, setMeals] = useState({});

 const searchMeals = async meals => {
 const res = await axios.get(
  `https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${meals}`
  );
 console.log(res.data);
 setMeals({ meals: res.data });
 };

 return (
 <div className='App'>
  <Search searchMeals={searchMeals}></Search>
  <Meals searchMeals={searchMeals} meals={meals}></Meals>
 </div>
  );
  }

export default App;
```

**I created a component Meals with this inside:**

```
import React from 'react'
import MealsItem from './MealsItem'

const Meals = ({ meals}) => {

 return (


<div >
  {Object.keys(meals).map(meal=>(
    <MealsItem key={meal.idMeal} meal={meal}/>
  ))}
</div>

);

};



 export default Meals
```

**and then for the rendering part I created a MealsItems component:**

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';


const MealsItem = ({ meal :{strMealThumb, strMeal,}}) => {
 return (
 <Fragment>
  <div id='result-heading'>
    <h2>Search result for: {strMeal}</h2>
  </div>
  <div className='meal'>
    <img src={strMealThumb} alt={strMeal} />
    <div className='meal-info'>
      <h3>{strMeal}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  </Fragment>
 );
};
export default MealsItem;
```

When I search something: I see a unique item with nothing in it. No title, no image. In the console when I inspect the app I read {meals: Array(8)} and "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." I thought did write a unique key: key={meal.idMeal}.

**EDIT: I did try to write**

```
{meals.map(meal=>(
```

))}

to no avail, unfortunately. It gives me a type error meals.map is not a function.

This is the structure of the API:

```
{
  "meals": [
    {
      "idMeal": "52772",
      "strMeal": "Teriyaki Chicken Casserole",
      "strDrinkAlternate": null,
      "strCategory": "Chicken"
}
]
}
```

Edit # 2: This is what I get when I console.log(meals)

[console.log(meals)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMkYx.png)

Thank you to anyone willing to help! Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Reason is that you are using 
`Object.keys(meals).map`.
Instead, do this

```
{meals.map(meal=>(
   <MealsItem key={meal.idMeal} meal={meal}/>
))}
```

EDIT: Also set default value of meals state.

```
const [meals, setMeals] = useState([]); // dont use  useState({})
```

Otherwise in the initial render before meals are fetched there will be error as we try to map over an object.

Comment: Hello ssk, I tried it before when i do that I get this message : meals.map is not a function.

Comment: Please check the meals array anyway, I checked and it was an array. Anyway mapping over keys and using the key inside the map function won't get us anywhere. May be you need to do meals[key].idMeal

Comment: Thank you ssk for your help. I appreciate it! I did change the initial state on my App component and I used map over meals but it is still giving me this type error meals.map is not a function. How would I do meals[key].idMeal ? Thanks again.

Comment: can you do a console.log(meals) just before you call meals.map

Comment: Yes, this is what shows when I inspect after a search     {meals: {…}}
meals:
meals: (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object